# sendMultipartTextMessage and check message sent report issue in android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sms

I am making an app to send sendMultipartTextMessage to many contacts. App download a list of updates and send it to the contacts. The main problem is I want to make app check again for new update after sending previous updates. I want to check previous message is sent to all recipients. So the app will download new list and send it again. But the main problem I noted is that a multi part SMS gives its send reports after every part sent. And also "case Activity.RESULT_OK:" event fired many time, I mean more than the length of TextMessages and parts. Here is the code I am using, copied from some website.

```
    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
        {        
            String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
            String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

            PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
            PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        System.out.println("SMS SENT");
// msgcounter = length of recipients I want to send messages. 
                        msgcounter = msgcounter -1;
                        if (msgcounter < 0){
                                if (StartInfo){
                                    new RequestTask().execute(BaseUrl);
                                }
                        }else{
                            CreatMsg();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

            //---when the SMS has been delivered---
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode())
                    {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                        
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
            for (int number = 0; number < parts.size(); number++) { 
                    sentIntents.add(sentPI);
                    deliveryIntents.add(deliveredPI);

            }
            sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts,sentIntents, deliveryIntents);    
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else is looking for the same solution, it's because `registerReceiver` is being called multiple times, and hence the reports are being processed as many times as the receiver is registered.  Solution is to move `registerReceiver` out of `sendSMS`, and only call it once.